# Serving two domains with nginx with a shared resource in both domains

Tags: php, nginx

I have two domains www.foo.com and www.bar.com with a file structure like the following:

```
/var/www/foo/
/var/www/bar/
/var/www/resource/
```

I have php files in the folder "resource" that need to be available on both domains. I would like to have the following site structure:

```
www.foo.com/resource/index.php
www.bar.com/resource/index.php
```

What's the best way to setup nginx configs to serve a folder that is not web accessible (directly) in two different domains?

Comment: trick with .htaccess will work http://www.htaccessredirect.net/

Comment: Share Nginx config you have so we can fix an issue